# pandas: to_list for timestamp stores as epoch. How to store as iso format time stamp string

Tags: pandas

I have a timestamp column named `time` in pandas dataframe

a sample timestamp is

```
2021-01-17 18:11:23+00:00
```

and the column data type is

```
time     datetime64[ns, psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone...
```

now i am trying to convert the column to a list

```
df['time'].values.tolist(),
```

the above sample timestamp is now converted into epoch and show stored as

```
1610907083000000000
```

How can i tell pandas to store in iso string format rather than epoch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df['time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').values.tolist()
```

You can change `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'` with the format you like the most (I used the ISO 8601 format; see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for the format specs)